# Javascript script doesnt load ? What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, load

Hello guys i was messing around with javascript trying to create a countdown timer ! However i think the javascript in the head section doesnt load because even the alert message doesnt show up ! I am a newbie, guys what am i doing wrong ? also how can i put my variables on the html so they will show up ? Thanks for your time ... This is my code :

```
               <html>
              <head>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 alert("welcome");
                      function calc() {
                        var year,month,date,hour,minutes,seconds,temp ;
                        temp = new Date();
                        year = temp.getFullYear();
                        month = temp.getMonth();
                        date = temp.getDate();
                        hour = temp.getHours(); 
                        minutes = temp.getMinutes();
                        seconds = temp.getSeconds();


                       var thenyear,thenmonth,thendate,thenhour,thenminutes,thenseconds ;
                       var difyear,difmonth,difdate,difhour,difminutes,difseconds ;
                       thenyear = document.getElementById("year").value ;
                       thenmonth = document.getElementById("Month").value;
                       thendate = document.getElementById("date").value;
                       thenhour = document.getElementById("hour").value;
                        thenminutes = document.getElementById("min").value;
                       thenseconds = document.getElementById("sec").value;

                      difyear= thenyear - year ;
                      difmonth = thenmonth -month ;
                      difdate  = thendate - date ;
                       difhour = thenhour - hour;  
                       difminutes =thenminutes - minutes ;
                      difseconds = thensec - seconds ;
                 alert("Time Remaing": + difyear + "Years" + difmonth +" Months" + difhour + "Hours" + difminutes + "Minutes" + difseconds+ " Seconds");
            }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Countdown Timer </p>
<form onsubmit="calc();">
Date/Month/Year 
<select id="date" name="date">
  <script type="text/javascript">

  for(var i = 1; i < 32; i++){
    document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
  }
  </script>
</select>
<select id="Month" > 
<option value="1">January </option>
<option value="2">February </option>
<option value="3">March </option>
<option value="4">April </option>
<option value="5">May </option>
<option value="6">June </option>
<option value="7">July </option>
<option value="8">August </option>
<option value="9">September </option>
<option value="10">Octomber </option>
<option value="11">November </option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="year" name="year">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var myDate = new Date();
  var year = myDate.getFullYear();
  for(var i = year; i < 3001; i++){
    document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
  }
  </script>
</select> <br>
Hour(0-23)/Minutes/Seconds

  <input type="text" id="hour"> 
  <input type="text" id="min">
  <input type="text" id="sec">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? I found one error rather quickly - `alert("Time Remaing":` <-- see that colon?

Comment: A JSFIDDLE may help!

Comment: Check for errors in your console, sometimes browser extensions block alerts.

Comment: Developer tools say that i needed <!DOCTYPE html> ( which i changed it and still nothing ) at the begining and it says something about : Back navigation caching :/